# How to solve this error in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

#My Model

```
from django.db import models

class Tutorial(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=''),
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, default=''),
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

#my 0001.py migration file

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Tutorial',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('published', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Why is the model neglecting the title, description fields even I mentioned them clearly???
I deleted the init0001.py file re run the migrations again but not resolved

Comment: have you run **python manage.py makemigration** ???

Comment: yes I did the migrations n number of times from yesterday but don't know why it is not getting the that 2 fields. i am trying for one day but not getting?

Answer (score 0):

probably you didn't run makemigrations command.

run:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

then run:

`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I did the migrations so only I got that 0001.init.py file and I deleted and repeated the migration but not getting them! :(

Comment: you have added commas in after your model fields, please remove those.

Comment: yes, I recognized it and the issue is resolved now. Thank you! :) @Tasnuva

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all because I gave commas in models for after every field so it did not take them into init0001.py file